# How to debug Meteor process death?

Tags: node.js, debugging, meteor

**Background**

I've set up vanilla "leaderboard" Meteor example. However, after ~12 hours of work, Meteor processes silently die (all of them, node* and mongo*).

There's nothing helpful in stdout, just the usual "App running at...". There's nothing suspicious in Kadira either. Memory consumption (~140 MB) and CPU utilization (~0.5%) are stable during whole process lifetime.

**Question**

Is there a way to figure out why Meteor processes were stopped? Have nodejs crashed? Have something sent a kill signal, or something else happend entirely? Right now I'm not even sure where to post the issue...

**Setup details**

Meteor is running in dev mode (insecure, etc) on Amazon EC2 t2-micro instance behind nginx. OS is Ubuntu 14.04 Server LTS. Connection upgrade to Websockets works correctly. Kadira instrumentation is enabled. Meteor version is 0.8.2

Comment: does it happen in the production mode? ie if you bundle your app as a node app and run it from a node script?

Comment: I don't know, haven't tried it yet. I'll try and post the results.